# Unable to read "#N/A" as string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having problem in reading "`#N/A"` as string.

Tried using both "keep_default_na=False" and "na_filter = False".
It is working out for "`NA`", "`N/A`", "`#NA`" but not for "`#N/A`".

Comment: Welcome on SO, what do you mean by reading? if it is from a csv, you have the parameter `na_values` that can be used to add specific string like yours to become `NaN` values, even if according to the doc `#N/A` should already be converted

Comment: I am reading from an Excel

Comment: when u used only ```keep_default_na```, without combining with ```na_filter```, it still doesn't work?

Comment: >>when u used only keep_default_na, without combining with na_filter, it still doesn't work?
Correct; it is still not working.